# Combine two expect statements that perform check on single json response

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm writing a test to check that a function in my Node.js application which returns this `JSON` structure:

```
    }
     id: 1,
     name: 'John Doe',
     email: 'j@doe.com',
     phone: '+123',
     suppliers: [ 
       { 
         id: 1, 
         name: 'Supplier1' 
       } 
     ] 
   }
```

I have this `expect`:

```
    expect(res.body.users[0]).to.be.an.instanceof(Object)
      .that.includes.all.keys([
        'id',
        'name',
        'suppliers',
      ]);
```

I also want to check there are details in `suppliers`. I could just add this in another `expect`:

```
    expect(res.body.users[0].suppliers[0]).to.be.an.instanceof(Object)
      .that.includes.all.keys([
        'id',
        'name',
      ]);
```

Is it possible to combine both into one `expect` statement though?

Comment: Why do you need to make that into one expect? Do you consider it adds any value? In terms of readability, it would be worse, because expect lets you add checks or assertions over "one" thing. If you want to check both at the same time, you would have to assert against the entire object from users into suppliers.

Comment: What do you mean by "assert against the entire object from users into suppliers"?

Comment: you would have to check the users first element against "something", and that something should contain the suppliers array. I think that is harder to read than using two expects